# React Native Expo not loading local files

Tags: ios, react-native, filesystems

I am developing app where local files are stored in user phone's file system. When I try to check if file exists with

```
var info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(`${AppConstants.APP_FOLDER}/main.png`);
console.log(info.exists);
```

It will print true. But if I try to read contents of file after checking:

```
var content = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(`${AppConstants.TILE_FOLDER}/main.png`);
console.log(content.length);
```

It freezes and nothing will be printed. I've tested my app on IOS in Expo Go.
The filepath is like that: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../app_folder/main.png`

File system works properly with loading online files by url and images can be shown, while in my case they can't. How should I solve my problem? What additional data I need to provide? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer.  But, I had something similar happen to me.  You can't really trust `console.log()` to tell you what code is executing.

I was reading in a file and then processing the data within it.  It appeared as if the `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync()` was hanging because my `console.log()` message that was directly after the FileSystem call was not being printed.  But, it turned out that the problem was inside my processing code.

Once I focused on my processing code, I found the problem and corrected it.  Perhaps this is what's happening in your case?